# Latex page numbering in R markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am creating a report in R markdown using LaTex and want a special page numbering. It should say "Seite i von n" at the bottom of each page, which is german for "page i of n" (where i is current page and n is total page number). I managed to do that for all but the front page, there is still only says "i" (i.e. "1"). So if there were 3 pages total, it would say "1" on the first page, "Seite 2 von 3" on the second and "Seite 3 von 3" on the third. What to I need to change such that it says "Seite 1 von 3" on the first page?

This is my code:

```
---
title: "Bericht zur [......]"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  - \usepackage{graphicx}
  - \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{hyperref}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{placeins} 
---


\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{Seite \thepage\ von \pageref*{LastPage}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\begin{table}[!h]
...
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[!h]
...
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[!h]
...
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a LaTeX question, answered here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30228 .  You already have most of that implemented; all you need to add is a line

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

somewhere on the first page, and you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your custom fancy pagestyle to all plain pages (title page, chapter pages etc.) via the command `\fancypagestyle{plain}[fancy]{}`

```
---
title: "Bericht zur ..."
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{graphicx}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{hyperref}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{placeins} 
---


\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}[fancy]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{Seite \thepage\ von \pageref*{LastPage}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\begin{table}[!h]
...
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[!h]
...
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[!h]
...
\end{table}
```