# How to add logo to top right of PDF document

Tags: r, yaml, latex, r-markdown

I am making a pdf document in which I want two logos in the top right of the page. I found great examples of using the latex 'fancy' package. When I replicate the example I receive this error `! LaTeX Error: File 'fancyhdr.sty' not found.` I am new to latex and have only used in Rstudio when knitting documents. How do I add this file or how do I install the latex package 'fancy'. I am using a 2017 macbook pro and making this document in R Studio.

```
---
title: "Test"
date: "Updated: `r format(Sys.time(), '%Y-%m-%d')`"
output: pdf_document
urlcolor: blue
indent: true
header-includes: 
 - \usepackage{indentfirst}
 - \usepackage{graphicx}
 - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 - \pagestyle{fancy}
 - \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{ribbitr.png}}
 - \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{nsf_logo.png}}
 - \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
 - \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}

---
```

[image: Render Error]

Comment: Generally, it depends on the TeX/LaTeX distribution, but gennerally speaking, that may help: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages#Manual_installation.

Comment: @Jake Do you use tinytex, mactex or texlive?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hmm how would I check? I use what is included in an Rmarkdown document.

Comment: @Jake Can you show a screenshot of the error message you get?

Comment: You can see the answers in the following link:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/27982052/2857542

Comment: sorry to revive this thread but I am still having the issue. @rral I have tried all the solutions on that thread.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have updated the post with a screen shot showing my error message

Comment: @Jake Thanks! the problem is that you are using an outdated version of texlive. You either have to install texlive2022 in order to install new packages in a normal way, or you have to switch to an historic repository to get a new package for the outdated texlive2021 you currently have installed.

Comment: You can find instructions on how to install texlive2022 at https://tug.org/texlive/

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ok so the logos are now appearing at the top for all the pages except the first page. How would I adjust my above yaml so the first page mirrors the following pages?

Comment: @Jake see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67056735/2777074